# Why is my phoneGap ipa file not installing on my device and getting stuck on install loop?

Tags: ios

I created a phonegap IOS app using the latest version (3.6.3) and it built fine in Phone Gap Build. I added it to iTunes and tried to install it on my phone but it gets stuck on 'Installing...' and just stays like that.

After some research I:

- Double checked I had the latest version of PG
- Make sure the widget ID in the config file matched the id when I created the app in apple developer site so it's like 'com.myorganization.myfineapp'
- I created the certificate and ID's in the developer site to the best of my knowledge using all available tutorials
- Tried this on two devices both using iOS7

BUT it still gets stuck on the install loop. What do I do? I'm new to using Apple's identifiers and licenses, etc.

Comment: I've had this. The problems I had were making sure the UDID was correct/the device was authorised and yes, generating the certs. Just do it all again to make sure.

Comment: Interesting nick choice. Did you add those two devices on your provisioning file? You need to get the UUID from the device and add it on the Apple Developer center.

Comment: @SubjectiveEffect Can you please give me detailed instruction on how to do this? I've followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3Y1amVx_zM

I have to create 3 different certs and I can easily miss this again. I need to know exactly which one to pay attention to and where to enter the UDID.

Comment: @sanfor I know how to get the UDID, but can you please tell me exactly where I need to add it in the Apple Developer Center?

Comment: It's in the list of items; Certs, Identifiers and then Devices. Go into Devices and add your devices.